# Where to put shared Apache vhost configuration in Debian?

Tags: debian, apache-virtualhost

I have several vhosts that share some lines of configuration and I would like to put this common configuration in a separate file and include it in these vhosts. I am not sure what would be the best (logical) location for this common configuration.

I suppose `/etc/apache2` is the best. None of `sites-..`, `mods-..` or `conf-..` are appropriate since this included code should not be activated by itself.

Note: I know I can put it anywhere and just include it from there. I am asking whether there is a common best practice location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is, else if would be already be there. :-)

I usually do just as you proposed, I create my own includes directory.